# How to display public ip of ec2_instance after terraform creation

Tags: terraform

I would like to display the public_ip of aws_instance created by terraform after terraform execution.

However, only the global IP of the first server appears.

My source code is as follows.

```
resource "aws_instance" "main" {
  count         = "3"
  ...
}


output "ec2_global_ips" {
  value = "${aws_instance.main.*.public_ip}"
}
```

Is something wrong grammar?
Let me know if you have to know how to display array values as output in terraform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
output "ec2_global_ips" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.main.*.public_ip}"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
output "ec2_global_ips" {
  value = [for instance in aws_instance.main : instance.public_ip]
}
```