# How to get public IP of EC2 instance in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
resource "aws_instance" "node" {
  for_each               = var.node_map
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.development-public-1b.id
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.nodes.key_name
  instance_type          = each.value.type
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.dev-ec2-sg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  
  tags          = {
    Name        = each.key
  }

  root_block_device {
    volume_type     = "gp2"
    volume_size     = each.value.size
    delete_on_termination   = true
  }  
}
```

I am trying to get the public IP associated with each of my ec2 instance as

```
output "instance_public_ip" {
  value       = {
    "${aws_instance.node.*.nodeid}" = "${aws_instance.node.*.public_ips}"  
  }
  description = "The public IP address of the main server instance."
}
```

But I get the following error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on node-updated.tf line 194, in output "instance_public_ip":
 194:     "${aws_instance.node.*.nodeid}" = "${aws_instance.node.*.public_ips}"  

This object does not have an attribute named "nodeid".
```

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on node-updated.tf line 194, in output "instance_public_ip":
 194:     "${aws_instance.node.*.nodeid}" = "${aws_instance.node.*.public_ips}"  

This object does not have an attribute named "public_ips".
```

If you could please let me know how can I access the PUBLIC IP after it is associated with the instance. Thanks in advance for the suggestions!!

Comment: The attributes are `id` and `public_ip`. You can see this at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance

Comment: Hi, I have tried ```public_ip``` but that doesnt work....
```Error: Unsupported attribute

  on node-updated.tf line 194, in output "instance_public_ip":
 194:     "${aws_instance.node.*.id}" = "${aws_instance.node.*.public_ip}"  

This object does not have an attribute named "public_ip".```

Comment: Why do you have aws_instance.node.*.id and not just aws_instance.node.id?

Comment: Got it correct at below stackoverflow link, Hope it will help others reaching here... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881459/how-to-display-public-ip-of-ec2-instance-after-terraform-creation

Answer (score 0):

associate_public_ip_address = true
should be done on the part of the subnet after you have written the script for vpc.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
    cidr_block = "172.16.0.0/16"

    tags = {
      "name" = "tf-example"
    }
}

# AWS SUBNET ATTACHED TO THE AWS VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "172.16.10.0/24"
  availability_zone = "af-south-1a"

  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    "name"  = "tf-example"
  }
}
```